# Step-Up Transformer parameters

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, inductance, transformator

Currently I am tinkering on a project including a high-voltage output.

**My current design is:**

Use a power-op amp (OPA547 [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa547.pdf) ) with +-24V-Rails at x4 non-inverting gain and feed it with a +-5V signal (sinus, 30 Hz>F>1 kHz). Feed the output of this op-amp into a common 230 V->9 V transformer - but with primary and secondary reversed. So 9 V->230 V (See Datasheet [Transformer Datasheet](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/amgis-llc/L01-6351/2137081))

This way I am hoping to get:
+/-5V * 4 * 230V/9V =~ +-500V

**My Questions are:**

1. As the OPA547 can only drive .5A peak a I want to have +/-20V I will need an impedance of at least 40 Ω accross the secondary. As the transformer datasheet does not state any inductances: Is there a "hands-on" value to use for this class of transformer?
2. As I recon the winding inductance across frequency L(f) will stay somewhat constant, the impedance will rise nearly linearly across frequency Z(f)=2* pi * f * L(f)=~ 2 * pi * f * L(30 Hz).
   Is this true?
3. What other implementations are usually used for this sort of design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a "hands-on" value to use for this class of transformer?*

The primary inductance might be about 10 henries (my best hands-on estimate). This means a magnetization reactance (at 50 Hz) of 3142 Ω. From 230 volts, it would take a magnetization current of 73.2 mA. Pretty nominally typical.

Based on the turns ratio squared relationship you can calculate the 9 volt secondary to have a self-inductance of \$(\frac{9}{230})^2 \times 10\text{ henries}\$ = 15.3 mH.

> *sinus, 30 Hz>F>1 kHz*

At 30 Hz, this will be an impedance of 2.9 Ω and, this is far lower than the 40 Ω you require. So, to avoid this problem, you would **not** be able to operate at a frequency below about 416 Hz.

However, the trouble with operating a regular mains transformer at 416 Hz (or above) is that the eddy current losses will be significantly increased. Eddy currents are formed in the steel laminates of the transformer; this is why we keep them thin (and insulated from each other) but 416 Hz may prove problematic.

For transformers that operate at kHz frequencies i.e. audio transformers we make the laminations very thin indeed to avoid significant eddy current losses.

> *What other implementations are usually used for this sort of design?*

Well, you've only described what you consider to be an implementation. You haven't described what you actually want to achieve so I can't answer that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to provide a +/-500V, 20mA max. AC (30Hz>f>1kHz) output from a +/-5V input. So i want to buil a device i connect to my ARB, feed in a sine-wave and get a high voltage output. (Ranging, On/Off, Smarts etc. is taken from a different design). Currently i have +/-5V IN -> Variable Gain Amp with +/-10V max -> power amp (OPA547) with fixed x2 gain. This is driven into a 230/9V Trafo (in reverse->x25) to provide +/-500V nom. at max. 5W. The Amps and ranging is verified by simulation and prototypes. Now i am wondering how to implement the x25 via an transformator.

Comment: You need a more powerful driver like an audio amplifier capable of 10 watts in my opinion @ElectronicsStudent. But you may well have eddy current problems at the higher frequencies and, it may be necessary to wind your own transformer on a large ferrite core.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I remeber vaguely from university, that the output impedance Zo is transformed to the Input Zi with (1/r)^2. So +/-500V would give 353V RMS. With 10mA RMS max. this gives a minimum Zi of 353V/10mA*(1/25)^2 = 56Ohm. If a lower output impedance is connected (e.g higher RMS current) the output voltage will drop as the .5A op amp is no longer able to provide the full voltage swing if Zi < 40Ohm. Eddy loses and stuff aside as i want to use a toroidal because of this - is this assumption correct in your opinion?

Comment: The basic self-inductance of the secondary is in parallel with the value you just calculated. It is this parallel connection of circa 15.3 mH that kills your assumption. That 15.3 mH (as I calculated in my answer) is always present whether you have a high-voltage load or not. Real transformers are far, far from ideal.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!